# PHP Curl and Browser difference

Tags: php, curl

When I type address `www.randomDomain.com` in browser and I read page source,

I see `<tag attrib1="value" attrib2="value2">`

But when I want to use PHP Curl to get content of this page,

I see this in source `<tag attrib1="value" attrib2='value2'>`

Sometimes the `"` sign is replaced by `'` sign. Why?

That reason causes problems with using right pattern of `preg_match()`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we don't mange troll.com, and this question is essentially unanswerable, except for random guesses.

Comment: Ask the people who create the html code for troll.com, why they use " and sometimes '. Maybe they don't want their code parsed automatically.

Comment: You think about the wrong problem. The problem you have is that you use regex to parse HTML instead of using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: I am guessing that they actually use `''` in some cases, but whatever browser you are using just converts everything to `""` on the fly.

Comment: HTML allows you to use either type of quote in attributes. If you're writing code that parses HTML, you have to be able to handle both cases.

Comment: troll.com is only random trollish example

Answer (score 3):

You aren't looking at the source in your browser (you can usually find that via the View menu (View → Developer → View Source in Chrome)). You are looking at the DOM Inspector (built into the browser developer tools) which shows an HTML-like representation of the current state of the DOM, not the original HTML source code.

Answer (score 2):

Both `"` and `'` are valid. The solution is to not use regex to parse HTML. Use the [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class instead:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl)

$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Some sites randomly "rotate" tags, class names, and other stuff to make content scraping more difficult, maybe that's the reason why ' is sometimes displayed because of "

I don't believe curl changes anything in the source code (using curl for 10 years), so if it's the only issue you experience, you can easily modify your preg_match rule to look for " OR '

Comment: If the objective would have been to make parsing more difficult swapping `"` for `'` is just about as useless as it gets